# Divisibility implications proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I would like some help setting up the proof for this. It's a simple enough idea, but I struggle with proofs for these the most, because it just seems so obvious to me.

Prove: if $a$, $b_1$, $b_2$ are integers, and $a\mid b_1$ and $a\mid b_2$ then $a\mid b_1+b_2$ and $a\mid b_1-b_2$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if $a|b_1,b_2$ it follows $b_1=am,b_2=an$ for some $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and so $b_1+b_2=am+an=a(m+n)$ and so $a|(b_1+b_2)$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If $a\mid b_1$, then there is an integer $n_1$ such that $b_1=an_1$. Similarly for $b_2$. Now what is $b_1+b_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a \mid b_1$ and $a \mid b_2$.

By definition of divisibility, $a \mid b_1 \iff b_1 = k_1a$ and $ a \mid b_2 \iff b_2 = k_2a,\;$ where  $k_1, k_2$ are integers.

So $\;b_1 + b_2 = k_1a + k_2 a = (k_1 + k_2) a \implies a\mid (b_1 + b_2)$

Follow the same logic to show that $a \mid b_1$ and $a \mid b_2$ implies $a \mid (b_1 - b_2)$.